# Writing an if statement in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to write a program that displays all items inside of a model property. I am new to this and am stuck here..

Here is my code.

```
public class SubscriptionModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int SubscriptionID { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
        public bool inBasicPackage { get; set; }
        public bool inBasicPlusPackage { get; set; }
        public bool inAdvancedPackage { get; set; }
        public bool inAdvancedPlusPackage { get; set; }
    }
```

```
@model IEnumerable<PricingPackages.Models.SubscriptionModel>


@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div>Basic Package</div>
@if(model.inBasicPackage == true){
//Model.ServiceName ??? --> not sure what to write here
}
```

new code

```
<div>Basic Package</div>
@foreach (SubscriptionModel nextItem in Model)
{
    @if (nextItem.inBasicPackage)
    {
        <div>@nextItem.ServiceName</div>
    }
}
```

I have added a "packages" method in the controller to display each package

```
 public class SubscriptionModelsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly PricingPackagesContext _context;

        public SubscriptionModelsController(PricingPackagesContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: SubscriptionModels
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.SubscriptionModel.ToListAsync());
        }

        public IActionResult Packages()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change model in the if to have an uppercase M

```
@if (Model.isBasicPackage)
{
    // whatever html you want to show
}
```

If your view model is an IEnumerable you will need to wrap it in a for loop

```
@foreach(SubscriptionModel nextItem in Model) 
{
    @if (nextItem.isBasicPackage)
    {
        // whatever html you want to show
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ok I'll try this. Can you please show the foreach you wrote?

Comment: Yeah sure thing

Comment: Now I am receiving "Reference not set to an instance of an object" . I just added my new code at the bottom.

Comment: Are you calling index or packages from the controller? The packages method only returns the view but no view model which means Model will be null

Comment: Got it! Makes sense.